# Why doesn't memset clear all of the elements in an array of structs?

Tags: c

Here is my code snippet

```
typedef struct Position
{
    short X;
    short Y;
} Pos;

Pos Block[25*25+1];

void Clear_String (void)
{
    memset (&Block, 0, sizeof (Pos));
}
```

Here is my full code in plain text: [Click Me](https://raw.github.com/kevin-dong-nai-jia/Console-Snake/master/Console-Snake%20v1.4.0.c)

Why `void Clear_String (void)` doesn't clear all of the elements in structure?

Comment: The elements of none, some, or all? You got the wrong element size in `Block` -- is that the only one?

Comment: Please be more specific. There are eight structures in this code fragment. Which is the one that is not being cleared? And which members are not being cleared? We are not psychic.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Oh sorry, only `Unfilled[]` and `Block[]` is not cleared.

Comment: You could have saved everybody a lot of time by removing the irrelevant structures from your code.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Yep, I've removed irrelevant codes. It looks more concise now. BTW, I've finished my snake: [Here!](https://github.com/kevin-dong-nai-jia/Console-Snake) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block and unfilled are arrays of Pos. You are zeroing only the first item since you pass sizeof (Pos).

Comment: so, is this correct: `memset (&Block   , 0, sizeof (Pos)*(25*25+1));`?

Comment: It's best to refer to the variable itself, sizeof (Block).  It's also safer if you were to change the number of items in the the future.

Comment: @KVD: `memset(&Block, 0, sizeof(Block))` is easier, less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You would do better to write:

```
void Clear_String (void)
{
    memset(Block,    0, sizeof(Block));
    memset(Unfilled, 0, sizeof(Unfilled));
    memset(&Erase,   0, sizeof(Erase));
    memset(&Draw,    0, sizeof(Draw));
    memset(&Predict, 0, sizeof(Predict));
    memset(&Cookie,  0, sizeof(Cookie));
  //memset(&Block,   0, sizeof(Block));  // No need to set it twice
    memset(&Move,    0, sizeof(Move));
}
```

Note that you should not pass the address of the array (so just `Block` instead of `&Block`). The latter will work, but it isn't what you intended (the type of the variable being passed is not the same, though as it ends up munged to a `void *`, it isn't obvious).  You don't need to zero `Block` twice. And you should specify the size of the named object, not the size of the type of the named object.

The only time that it requires care is if you are passing arrays by argument, or if the arrays are defined in a separate file from the code the zeroes them.  If the declaration is `extern SomeType somearray[];`, you can't apply `sizeof()` to it.

Comment: Great! Appreciate your answer. Really clear. Thanks.